# Assignment operator with a constant class member

Tags: c++, class, constants

I have a class called RSArray which contains a constant data member. But for this class I want to create a custom assignment operator. See code below: -

```
class RSArray
{
private:
    int *data;
    const int max_size;
public:
    RSArray(size) : max_size(size)
    {
        data = new int[max_size];
    }
    RSArray &operator=(const RSArray &src)
    {
         data = new int[src.max_size];
         max_size = src.max_size
    }

}

int main()
{
    RSArray one(10), two(15);
    one = two;
}
```

The above code giving me error when assignment operator is called because we can't change value of a const data member.

Is there any other way to get rid of this error?

Comment: Where do you initialize `max_size`? Is this the same for all instances or individually set when you create a new one? For me it looks like you rather want to use a `std::vector<int> data;` class member variable.

Comment: Just don't decalre max_size as const if you want to support assignment.

Comment: What you're asking for doesn't make any sense. If there is data in the instances that can't change, then you can't also expect to make one instance look like another - because if the other instance looks different, then doing so would be changing it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it looks like they are implementing `homework::vector<int>`

Comment: @Caleth I am giving advice here regardless of the OPs situation, which is completely irrelevant for SO Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other way to get rid of this error?

Yes, remove the `const` from `max_size`. Assignment by definition mutates the target.

Comment: Ok, but I just wanted to know whether assignment operator supports const or not